# How my HTML application treats relative addresses depends too much on how it is run

Tags: javascript, relative-path, jscript, hta, applicationhost

My HTML application file `F:\relroot\libname.lib\textapp.hta` (name altered) contains the following function:

```
function fullNameOfFile(filename) { 
     var fso = newMedium(); return fso.GetAbsolutePathName(filename)
}
```

When I run the application via `Open` or double-click it in the directory,

`fullNameOfFile("../etc.txt")` returns `"F:\relroot\etc.txt"` [runs perfectly!].

When I run it via `Open with:Microsoft HTML Apln Host`, however:

`fullNameOfFile("../etc.txt")` returns `"C:/Windows/etc.txt"` [wrong number!].

How should I code to get to work regardless of how the application is run?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CreateTextFile not working when hta is set to open as notepad by default (javascripting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742435/createtextfile-not-working-when-hta-is-set-to-open-as-notepad-by-default-javasc)

Comment: I don't use `.CreateTextFile()`, but I _did_ use `.OpenTextFile()`.  Would that method have similar issues?

Comment: Did you read the proposed dup? The answer has nothing to do with a method using the system path, the answer is about how to change that path ...

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have "Aspie-rigged" a solution (or maybe two)

Apparently opening the HTML application via <kbd>Open</kbd> (or double-click) presets the "current" directory to the directory containing the app while opening via <kbd>Open With</kbd>:<kbd>Microsoft® HTML Application Host</kbd> uses a default directory (like «`C:\WINDOWS\system32`»)

```
var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var wasDir = shell.currentDirectory  /* OPTIONAL: push original current directory
                                            to allow restoration later */
    var swDL = false;                      // for differences in device file format
    var splitter = (swDL ? '/'   : '\\')   // foreslash v. backslash
    var slashes  = (swDL ? '///' : '//')   /* slashes between scheme/protocol
                                                and authentication/host */
var lhref = swDL ? unescape(location.href) : document.URL;
var newDir = lhref.slice(location.protocol.length + slashes.length,
                   lhref.lastIndexOf(splitter));
/*
//  uncomment this block for an "inside window"

alert("Entering Directory: «" + wasDir + "»\n" +
         "Protocol/Scheme: «" + location.protocol + "»\n" +
           "Location HREF: «" + lhref + "»\n" +
         "Trial Directory: «" + newDir + "»");
*/
shell.currentDirectory = newDir
```

It seems to work like a charm on my system (Dell PC, Internet Explorer/¿Edge).  I threw in some comments as well in case the next user needs to tweak it for *their* system.